# Permissão de arquivo MPDF

Tags: php

Boa tarde amigos,

Estou criando pastas dinâmicamente conforme a senha do usuário.

```
 $dir = "relatorio/".$password;
 if(!file_exists($dir)){
 umask(0);
 mkdir($dir, 0777,true);

 }
 $path = "relatorio/".$password."/".$nomeFormulario.".pdf";
 $mpdf->Output($path, "F");

 //$mpdf->Output();
 header("location: sucesso.php");

 exit();
```

Esse código é executado toda vez que o usuário abre o sistema, assim que ele abre o sistema e preenche um questionário diferente, é criado dentro da pasta relatório, uma pasta com a senha dele e em seguida dentro desta pasta é gerado um PDF utilizando o MPDF, porém apenas o primeiro arquivo em pdf fica com permissão 777, o resto não fica.

Alguma dica ?

Gracias :)

Comment: Conseguiu a solução ? Atualmente estou com um problema similar